# How can I fix this exception

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner, indexoutofboundsexception

Here is my code to distinguish the differences between two txt files. The only problem is i get an out of bounds exception if i dont subtract 1 from the arrayList, so right now it is not running for all of the elements, how do i fix this?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class myfilereader
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException
    {

        int temp = 0;
        ArrayList<String> ArrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> ArrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> ArrayList3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        try
        {
            Scanner File1 = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Home/Desktop/File1.txt"));
            while (File1.hasNext())
            {
                ArrayList1.add(File1.next());
            }

            Scanner File2 = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Home/Desktop/File2.txt"));
            while (File2.hasNextLine())
            {
                ArrayList2.add(File2.next());
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (String ArrayList : ArrayList1) 
        {
            System.out.println("File 1: " + ArrayList1);
        }
        for (String ArrayList : ArrayList2) 
        {
            System.out.println("File 2: " + ArrayList2);
        }

        if(ArrayList1.size()>ArrayList2.size())
        {
            for(int i=0; i<ArrayList1.size()-1; i++)
            {
                if(ArrayList1.get(i).equals(ArrayList2.get(i)))
                {
                    temp++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(ArrayList2.size()>ArrayList1.size())
        {
            for(int i=0; i<ArrayList2.size()-1; i++)
            {
                if(ArrayList2.get(i).equals(ArrayList1.get(i)))
                {
                    temp++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(temp == 0)
        System.out.println("The files are the same.");
        else
            System.out.println("There are " + temp + " differences between the files");

    }
}
```

Comment: You are checking first in your code if ArrayList2.size() > ArrayList1.size() and after that you are operating your for-loop from 0 to ArrayList2.size() length.

Because ArrayList2 is bigger, you will not find the last elements in ArrayList1 in point i ! I think your for-loop should go from 0 until ArrayList1.size() since that one is shorter

Comment: If one list is bigger than the other, how can you expect to loop through both of them with the same indices? Also, why don't you close the files when you're done reading them?

Comment: @AntonH That's not the problem. The for-condition is `i < ArrayList1.size()-1`, so it will stop right after `i == ArrayList1.size()-2` because of the strict less than. The correct condition would be `i < ArrayList1.size()`. The *actual* problem is that the OP is using the wrong limit: he should be using the *smallest* of the two sizes in his condition. Also, he should probably use a greater than or equals in his if-tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sara Seppola already mentioned, you need to use the *smallest* of the two sizes to compare the elements in the two lists. Currently, you're using the biggest of the two, which *guarantees* that you'll go out of bounds on the smaller list.

Also, you *should* be using `ArrayList1.size()` and not `ArrayList1.size()-1` in your loop limits, as the strictly less than check in your loop condition currently causes `i` to iterate from `0` to `ArrayList1.size()-2` - which is one too short. Again, the index-out-of-bounds is *not* caused by the `-1`, but rather because of the incorrect size used in the condition.

Finally, you're not accounting for the case where the lists have equal sizes. Currently, your code gives "The files are the same" since there's not if-test which passes when `ArrayList1.size() == ArrayList2.size()`.

```
if(ArrayList1.size() >= ArrayList2.size())
{
    // Here, ArrayList1.size() >= ArrayList2.size()
    // Use the smallest size as limit so we stay in bounds for both
    // In this case, that's ArrayList2.size()
    // When the lists have equal length, both sizes could be used
    // as limit so it doesn't really matter whether you use
    // > or >= in the test of the above if-statement
    for(int i=0; i<ArrayList2.size(); i++)
    {
        if(ArrayList1.get(i).equals(ArrayList2.get(i)))
        {
            temp++;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    // Here, ArrayList1.size() < ArrayList2.size()
    // so use ArrayList1.size() as the limit
    for(int i=0; i<ArrayList2.size(); i++)
    {
        if(ArrayList2.get(i).equals(ArrayList1.get(i)))
        {
            temp++;
        }
    }
}
```

There's still an error in your code though: you're only comparing corresponding elements. What about the extra elements from the larger list? Those should be counted as differences as well.

A quick fix would be to simply subtract the two sizes to get the number of extra elements in the bigger list, and use that as initial value for the number of difference:

```
if(ArrayList1.size() >= ArrayList2.size())
{
    temp = ArrayList1.size() - ArrayList2.size();
    // [for loop]
}
else
{
    temp = ArrayList2.size() - ArrayList1.size();
    // [for loop]
}
```

Of course, you could still simplify your code. You could use `Math.min(ArrayList1.size(), ArrayList2.size())` to get the smallest of the two sizes and remove the duplicated loop. You could also use `Math.abs(ArrayList1.size() - ArrayList2.size())` to get the number of extra elements, regardless whether `ArrayList1` or `ArrayList2` is the largest. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much everybody!!! I was able to understand everything and code it in a proper manner! :D

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
    if(ArrayList1.size()>ArrayList2.size())
    {
    //ArrayList1 is bigger!!!!

        for(int i=0; i<ArrayList1.size()-1; i++)
        {
            if(ArrayList1.get(i).equals(ArrayList2.get(i)))
            // ArrayList2 does not contain as many elements as ArrayList1
            {
                temp++;
            }
        }
    }
```

therefore. You can have your loop from 0 -> ArrayList.size() but be sure to use the shorter list as the limit for the loop! :-)

Comment: True, but the `-1` is still wrong. Using `ArrayList2.size()-1` would not check the last element in `ArrayList2`.

Comment: That is true :) If you want to go through the whole array you need to go from 0 -> Arraylist.size() like I already mentioned after the code

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can replace:

```
for(int i=0; i<ArrayList1.size()-1; i++)
```

With:

```
for (String s : ArrayList1)
```

This is called a *for-each* loop and can be used for more readable simpler iteration.

Comment: How would you compare matching elements in the two lists in this case? You need to compare element per element, so you need to use `i` to index both lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ArrayList1.size()>ArrayList2.size())
{
    for(int i=0; i<ArrayList1.size()-1; i++)
    {
        if(ArrayList1.get(i).equals(ArrayList2.get(i)))
        {
            temp++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here you first check if `ArrayList1` has more items than `ArrayList2`, and then you loop over the bigger `ArrayList1`, using `get(i)` on `ArrayList1` as well as `ArrayList2`.

Because `ArrayList1` has more items than `ArrayList2`, eventually you will `get` an item from at index X from `ArrayList1` that you cannot `get` from `ArrayList2` because `ArrayList2` contains less items.

Example: `ArrayList1` has 10 items and `ArrayList2` has 9 items. You enter the if because 10 > 9. Then at the last iteration in the for loop you do `ArrayList1.get(9)` which is fine because it has 10 items and this gets the 10th, but `ArrayList2.get(9)` will fail because it has only 9 items. 8 is the highest index you can work with.

The second if has the same problem, but the other way around.

A fix to stop the error from occurring would be to

```
for(int i = 0; i < ArrayList2.size(); i++)
{
    ...
```

This might not do what you want your code to do, but the error will be gone.